# meta_query compare >= not working but <= working?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
$today123 = date('Ymd');
$args123 = array (
        'post_type' => 'myType',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'=>'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'date',//this is a custom field, not the std 'date' field of wp
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today123,
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC' 
);
$variable=new WP_Query($args123);
```

to filter my custom post type based on a custom field, i use the query in a loop as intended and i check out the output with a couple of var_export

the query is completly ignoring my meta_query (i tried deleting the orderby but even without it, the metaquery simply isn't beign applied)

so i tempered a little with the code and checkout various outcomes in various situation and i found out something,

if use

```
'compare'   => '>=',
```

it gets ignored, and it returns all the posts even the ones that doesn't have a

```
'meta_date' >= date('Ymd')
```

but if i use the exact same code, putting

```
'compare'   => '<=',
```

magically the filter gets applied and working as i would expect the <= compare to work.

I may be missing something here, i need to retrieve the 'myType' posts that have a value of meta_date greater or equal to date('Ymd') and sort them by the meta_data in a ASC order...

Why compare '<=' works and compare '>=' doesn't? How can i achieve my desidered result?

EDIT:

"Funny" discovery: if i don't orderby and order, compare >= works...

Comment: what do you get if you `var_dump($variable)`

Comment: the wordpress query, with all the meta_query and everything else, <= and >= print the exact same query, only difference is the compare itself. 
This leads me to believe that the error is in wordpress itself because the WP_query has no errors...

Comment: Maybe you should just set the `orderby` to `meta_value` and not `meta_value_num`?

Comment: Sally CJ i tried that, i also tried with meta_value_date but all the same, it simply gets ignored only when using > and >= operators ( <= and = operators works without any problem)

Comment: In the code you used, keep everything the same (i.e. `'compare' => '>='` and `'orderby' => 'meta_value'`), and then do `echo $variable->request;` after the `WP_Query()` call. Copy the output of the `echo` and share it here. Then do the same after changing `compare` to `<=` while keeping `orderby` as `meta_value`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, i figured out a solution by myself after experimenting some more with the code, i will post it a solution now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a full investigation and a lot more debugging and code tempering I found out that using "date" as a meta field name generate a lot of "confusion" inside the wordrpess query itself as wordpress confuse the meta_query "date" field with the "date" itself, to avoid all this the solution is simply changing the name of the metafield from date to meta_date, doing that makes all the query on the field work as intended!